# Chatbot Trained on Substrate-based Chains and Repositories for General Reference and Help

Tags: parachain, rust, wasm, blockchain, documentation

I'd like to propose an idea for creating a general reference and help tool utilizing a chatbot trained on data from Substrate-based chains `(e.g., Polkadot, Kusama, Parachains)` and their associated repositories. While I don't plan to implement this myself, I am curious to discuss its feasibility and potential impact.

1. Would it be technically feasible to extract and preprocess the necessary data from these chains and repositories to train a chatbot model?
2. Do you think the resulting chatbot would provide valuable insights and assistance to developers?
3. Are there any potential legal or ethical concerns with using the data from these chains and repositories for this purpose?
4. Would the chatbot model be able to keep up with the constantly evolving nature of these ecosystems?

I'm interested in hearing your thoughts on this proposal, any suggestions for improving the idea, and any potential challenges that could arise.

Comment: I really like the idea / suggestion, but [polkadot forum](https://forum.polkadot.network/) is the better platform to have this discussion!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a technical question. The polkadot forum is the better place for it. But please make a post there!

Answer (score 1):

following the suggestion I duplicated this proposal in the polkadot forum:

https://forum.polkadot.network/t/chatbot-trained-on-substrate-based-chains-and-repositories-for-general-reference-and-help/2516